# Calculating area percentages of another vector file based on vector grid using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: coordinate-system, clip, vector-grid, equal-area

I have a grid (vector file) in ArcGIS Pro, and I want to calculate the percentages of the area of different anthrome types in the other vector file (Anthromes 12K DGG Dataverse) for each grid cell. I used the tool Summarize within to calculate the percentages (Add group percentages).

Those two shapefiles are in different projections. Which one should I convert if that is necessary?

The grid is in Lambert equal area projection (North America Lambert Conformal Conic) and anthromes are in EPSG:4326. However, according to metadata, the anthromes data have been produced using an equal area DGG system (Level 12 Icosahedral
Snyder Equal Area (ISEA) Aperture 3 Projection).

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would project the WGS84 data into the equal area projection as the units will be meaningful (metres) more info of the projection [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/projections/lambert-conformal-conic.htm#:%7E:text=Lambert%20conformal%20conic%20is%20a,away%20from%20the%20standard%20parallels.).